# Knowing how much \resizebox scales

Tags: graphics, scaling

Is it possible to know how much a `\resizebox` scales something for further use in a `\scalebox`?

To clarify, take this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\def\figurea{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\def\figureb{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-b}}
This is \texttt{fig-a} with its natural size:

\figurea
\bigskip

This is \texttt{fig-b} with its natural size:

\figureb
\bigskip

This is \texttt{fig-a} scaled to fit the page width:

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\figurea}
\bigskip

How do I rescale \texttt{fig-b} to keep its relative size compared to \texttt{fig-a} without knowing its actual size?
\bigskip

\texttt{Insert a nice piece of code here :)}

\end{document}
```

I want to have `fig-b` with the same relative size to `fig-a` without actually knowing the size of any of them.

Also, as in the example, there will be text in between the figures, so putting them in the same `\resizebox` is not an option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\resizebox` is just `\scalebox` with a scale factor being the number that you ask for. So you can just persuade it to expose that number rather than just use it in a local group and discard it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\let\zz\Gscale@box
\long\def\Gscale@box#1{%
\xdef\thelastscalefactor{#1}%
\zz{#1}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\figurea{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\def\figureb{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-b}}
This is \texttt{fig-a} with its natural size:

\figurea
\bigskip

This is \texttt{fig-b} with its natural size:

\figureb
\bigskip

This is \texttt{fig-a} scaled to fit the page width:

\noindent%you need this:-)
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\figurea}
\let\savethis\thelastscalefactor
\bigskip

How do I rescale \texttt{fig-b} to keep its relative size compared to \texttt{fig-a} without knowing its actual size?
\bigskip

\noindent
\scalebox{\savethis}{\figureb}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But now my curiosity lies on "@CarLaTeX's comment". Must be something deep to justify three post edits `:)` (four if we count that @egreg already changed it on the first time).

Comment: @Carlatex is a lady and Italian and google suggests that perhaps your macro name wasn't a good word to use in the presence of such a person:-) (egreg is Italian and probably didn't require a nudge from Carlatex:-)

Comment: Ohhhhh... Didn't expect that... I'll be a little more careful with my abbreviations from now on `:)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
\resizebox{\fpeval{(2.5cm) / (5cm)}\textwidth}{!}{\figureB}
```

where `\fpeval` is provided by [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp).

Essentially you're resizing the image to a scaled version of `\textwidth` based on the ratio of the two figure's widths. This is known in this case, so it seems superfluous to evaluate `(2.5cm) / (5cm)` rather than just using `.5`. But in general this might not be known.

The following example is slightly different, using `2.5pc` for the smaller image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xfp}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\def\figureA{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\def\figureB{\includegraphics[width=2.5pc]{example-image-b}}

This is \texttt{figureA} with its natural size:

\figureA
\bigskip

This is \texttt{figureB} with its natural size:

\figureB
\bigskip

This is \texttt{figureA} scaled to fit the page width:

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\figureA}
\bigskip

How do I rescale \texttt{figureB} to keep its relative size compared to \texttt{figureA} without knowing its actual size?
\bigskip

\resizebox{\fpeval{(2.5pc) / (5cm)}\textwidth}{!}{\figureB}

\end{document}
```

You could also use

```
\resizebox{\fpeval{\textwidth * (2.5pc) / (5cm)}pt}{!}{\figureB}
```

since the result from `\fpeval` on dimensions is expressed in `p`oin`t`s.

---

If the figure dimensions are unknown, you can store the figures in boxes from which one can readily extract the `w`i`d`th and/or `h`eigh`t`. Here is the above example written with that in mind:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xfp}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\figureAbox}% Store figure a in a box
\savebox{\figureAbox}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\newsavebox{\figureBbox}% Store figure b in a box
\savebox{\figureBbox}{\includegraphics[width=2.5pc]{example-image-b}}

This is \texttt{figureA} with its natural size:

\usebox\figureAbox% figure a
\bigskip

This is \texttt{figureB} with its natural size:

\usebox\figureBbox% figure b
\bigskip

This is \texttt{figureA} scaled to fit the page width:

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox\figureAbox}% Scaled figure a
\bigskip

How do I rescale \texttt{figureB} to keep its relative size compared to \texttt{figureA} without knowing its actual size?
\bigskip

\resizebox{\fpeval{\textwidth * (\wd\figureBbox) / (\wd\figureAbox)}pt}{!}{\usebox\figureBbox}% Scaled figure b

\end{document}
```

Comment: To use this I must know the actual size of the pictures `T_T`. Is it possible to somehow hack into `\resizebox` to get the scaling factor? Or maybe measure them before and after scaling... I ask this because in my case I don't know the size of the pictures prior to loading them. (I load them with a `\forLoop`, and they usually change in size between one compilation an another so... Yeah, I'm a boring person `:)`). But I didn't know about `fpeval`. It'll be very useful. Thanks!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: You can store the pictures in a box and then retrieve the width/height as needed. I'll add some detail.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik the first thing `\resizebox` does is calculate the scale factor but normally it does not return that value it just uses it to call scalebox internally.

Answer (score 4):

Here I define `\Resizebox`, a variant of `\resizebox` that takes an optional argument; if absent it does the same as `\resizebox`, if present, it should be a (definable) control sequence where the scale factor is stored, for subsequent use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=40cm,paperwidth=21cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand\figureA{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\newcommand\figureB{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image-b}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Resizebox}[4][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \resizebox{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \else
    \begingroup
    \sbox0{#4}%
    \sbox2{\resizebox{#2}{#3}{#4}}%
    \@ifdefinable{#1}{\xdef#1{\fpeval{\wd2/\wd0}}}%
    \usebox{2}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\raggedright
This is \texttt{figure-a} with its natural size:

\figureA

\bigskip

This is \texttt{figure-b} with its natural size:

\figureB

\bigskip

This is \texttt{figure-a} scaled to fit the page width:

\Resizebox[\scaleforfigureA]{\textwidth}{!}{\figureA}

\bigskip

How do I rescale \texttt{figure-b} to keep its relative 
size compared to \texttt{figure-a} without knowing its actual size?

\bigskip

\texttt{Insert a nice piece of code here :)}

\scalebox{\scaleforfigureA}{\figureB}

\end{document}
```

[image]