# \includegraphics: get the "scale" value of a figure whose size is expressed by "width"

Tags: boxes, crop, includegraphics, scale

Lets take this string:

```latex
\boxed{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FIGURE.pdf}}
```

that generates this figure:

[image]

Now lets say that I need to crop the blank margins of the figure keeping the figure's size.

I though I could do it with something like:

```latex
\boxed{\includegraphics[trim = L B R T, clip, scale=x]{FIGURE.pdf}}
```

Where `L`, `B`, `R`, and `T` are respectively the left, bottom, right and top trimming values and `x` is the scaling value.

The following example should better explain my question:

```latex
\boxed{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{FIGURE.pdf}}\quad %
\boxed{\includegraphics[scale=0.238]{FIGURE.pdf}}\\

\boxed{\includegraphics[trim = 65 20 150 20, clip, width=0.4\textwidth]{FIGURE.pdf}}\quad %
\boxed{\includegraphics[trim = 65 20 150 20, clip, scale=0.238]{FIGURE.pdf}}
```

The previus code generates the following layout:

[image]

As you can see, using `scale` value instead of `width` lets me crop the figure keeping its size.

My question is: how can I get the exact (more or less) value of the scale parameter without go by trial and error? (My idea is to write some `Emacs Lisp` code to change the `LaTeX` code accordingly.)

I am open to any idea or suggestion.

**Note.** In most cases I use external software to crop my images (`pdfcrop`, `briss` etc.) but, sometimes, as in this case, they don't work so I need to trim manually.

Comment: The redefinition of `\Gscale@box` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409599/134574) does what you want.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you but I can't see how the redefinition of `\Gscale@box` should help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All graphics are written to the PDF with a scale factor. When you specify a size the package just converts it to an appropriate scale factor. You can make `\Gscale@box` remember that scale factor for you ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409599/134574)). You can use the same `\thelastscalefactor` as many times as you need:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\let\ORG@Gscale@box\Gscale@box
\long\def\Gscale@box#1{%
  \xdef\thelastscalefactor{#1}%
  \ORG@Gscale@box{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Measuring the image without actually using it
\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}\quad

\noindent % Using with the scale only
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}\quad
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=\thelastscalefactor]{example-image}}

\noindent
\fbox{%
  \makebox[0.4\textwidth][l]{% <-- trick to align without a tabular
    \includegraphics[trim = 65 20 150 20, clip, scale=\thelastscalefactor]{example-image}%
  }%
}\quad
\fbox{\includegraphics[trim = 65 20 150 20, clip, scale=\thelastscalefactor]{example-image}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image]

Comment: Please see that I need the figure to be trimmed but not resized. In your `scale=\thelastscalefactor` example the figure is resized too. Moreover I need to "phantom" in some way the figure expressed by `width` because I don't want it to be printed in my PDF.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi The figure was resized because I used `width=0.4\textwidth` in a narrower image, thus it was adjusted to fit the constraint of `width=0.4\textwidth`. You can use `scale=\thelastscalefactor` as many times as you want after you measured it, then the images will obey the constraint of `scale`, which does not resize them. Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by “‘phantom’ the figure”. Can you please explain?

Comment: Ok, I understood how to mesure the `scale` factor but in my layout I need to print only one figure, the scaled ones. So I need to "hide" the code from which I get the  scale amount. Only one figure has to be printed in my output.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi You can't measure the figure without including it somehow. However you can include the figure inside a box an simply not use it. You can do `\sbox0{\includegraphics[...]{...}}`, and from this point on `\thelastscalefactor` is known and you can use it at will. I edited in an example.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

You can keep the `width=` on the graphics and trim/clip separately so not affecting the scaling, see the last example here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}
\begin{document}



\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[clip,trim=1cm .5cm .7cm .1cm, width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}

\bigskip

\adjustbox{clip,trim=1cm .5cm .7cm .1cm}{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll use your solution in most cases but I accepted the Phelype Oleinik's solution because it answers better to my question.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi that's OK I'll survive without the tick:-)

Answer (score 4):

I never liked the idea of scaling and clipping at the same time, not knowing which comes first (keyword order means nothing).  This solution clips first then scales by using `\savebox` and `\adjustbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics[trim = 65 20 150 20, clip]{example-image}}%
\fbox{\adjustbox{width=0.4\textwidth}{\usebox\tempbox}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure this is what you are looking for, but here is a way to compute, for instance, 1000 times the desired scale factor, rounded to the nearest integer:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcount\myscale

\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{example-image}}%
\myscale=\numexpr 400*\textwidth / \wd0 \relax % 400 = 0.4×1000
\showthe\myscale                % displays 430 on the terminal

\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}

\includegraphics[scale=0.43]{example-image} % same width as above

\end{document}
```