# Making two figures the same scale and fit on a line

Tags: graphics, width

Let's say I have a bunch of images, (two in this MWE)

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{whacknot}
    \caption{Fritz-Qualdor count of greezable whacknotters}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{qualprift}
    \caption{Corrected null-count of pre-groused qualprifters}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Counting methods used in theta-analysis}
\end{figure}
```

Sure enough, I now have two images underneath each other of the same size.  However, what I *actually* want is to have two images of exactly the same scale, but both **at most** `.95\linewidth` (the images are generated programatically, but due to overzealous cropping, they all have a slightly different size). I could of course manually twiddle with a `[scale=something]` on all the figures, but that Is there a way to do this automatically in LaTeX?

Comment: So you want the two subfigures side-by-side, on the same line, but their combined width no more than `0.95\linewidth`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492188/189324 might help

Answer (score 3):

The `adjustbox` environment has a `max width` option, so you could place your side-by-side subfigures inside an `adjustbox`. This should preserve their original scales, but scale down both together if necessary. **Edit:** However, this would scale the subcaption as well. I'm not sure how to prevent this, but you can provide a `phantomsubcaption` and `label` in order to refer to the subfigures in the main `figure` caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,graphicx,subcaption}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}

\providecommand{\samelinefigs}[4]{%
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.95\linewidth}
{\includegraphics{#1}\phantomsubcaption\label{#2}}\quad
{\includegraphics{#3}\phantomsubcaption\label{#4}}
\end{adjustbox}
}

\begin{document}
Two smaller figures, unscaled:
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\samelinefigs{example-grid-100x100pt}{fig:grid}{example-image-4x3}{fig:4by3}
\caption{Caption for \subref{fig:grid} grid and \subref{fig:4by3} generic image.}
\end{figure}

Two larger figures, both scaled:
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\samelinefigs{example-image-16x10}{fig:16by10}{example-image-16x9}{fig:16by9}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

Original size of $16\times9$ figure:

\includegraphics{example-image-16x9}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this will badly scale the subcaption font

Comment: @wun Indeed. I've proposed a workaround in my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

One can modify the question [Print the "scale factor" on each figure as a watermark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/492352/189324) to save the previous scaling factor for usage in the next image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\let\ORG@Gscale@box\Gscale@box
\long\def\Gscale@box#1{%
  \xdef\thelastscalefactor{#1}%
  \ORG@Gscale@box{#1}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\imagea}
\newlength{\imageb}
\newbox\vhbox

\begin{document}

% Enter the image names here
\newcommand{\imgA}{example-image-16x10}
\newcommand{\imgB}{example-image-9x16}


\settowidth{\imagea}{\includegraphics{\imgA}}
\settowidth{\imageb}{\includegraphics{\imgB}}
\begin{figure}[h]
\ifdim\imagea>\imageb   
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{\imgA}
        \caption{Fritz-Qualdor count of greezable whacknotters}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=\thelastscalefactor]{\imgB}
        \caption{Corrected null-count of pre-groused qualprifters}
    \end{subfigure}
\else
    \setbox\vhbox\vbox{\includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{\imgB}}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=\thelastscalefactor]{\imgA}
    \caption{Fritz-Qualdor count of greezable whacknotters}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{\imgB}
    \caption{Corrected null-count of pre-groused qualprifters}
    \end{subfigure}
\fi
\caption{Counting methods used in theta-analysis}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not bad! Now to figure out how to extend this to a larger number of images...