# Repeat the same TikZ graphic to fill the entire page

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

## What I'm trying to do

I am creating some handwriting drill sheets. In these sheets, the exact same pattern is repeated horizontally and vertically over the entire page. The following 3 images were created using Inkscape, each of them represent the content of a single page that I want to create using TikZ.

[image]
[image]
[image]

## What I know

I just learned that I can define a pattern inside `\newsavebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox \mybox
\sbox \mybox {%
  \tikz{%
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.2);
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.4);
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.6);
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.8);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0, 0) {\usebox\mybox};
    \node at (2, 0) {\usebox\mybox};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also know that I can use loops to repeat the same pattern so that it fills the entire page (without exceeding the page borders).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox \mybox
\sbox \mybox {%
  \tikz{%
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.2);
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.4);
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.6);
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.8);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \row in {2,4,...,18} {
      \foreach \column in {2,4,...,14} {
        \node at (\column, \row) {\usebox\mybox};
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Sometimes the page dimension is changed using the `geometry` package. When that hapens, I need to manually update the number of iterations of the loop and see if the number of repetitions don't exceed the page border. I wish the loop automatically stopped when it reaches the right limit of the page or the bottom limit of the page.

I also know how to repeat something until the right limit of the page is reached by using `\xleaders`. (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38424)). I used that knowledge to repeat the tikz graphic (see minimal working example below). However, the problem is that multiple `tikzpicture` environment are used. I wished a single `tikzpicture` is used in order to reduce the complexity of the source code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox \mybox
\sbox \mybox {%
  \tikz{%
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.2);
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.4);
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.6);
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.8);
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  }%
}

\newcommand\asteriskfill{\leavevmode\xleaders\hbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0, 0) {\usebox\mybox};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \hfill\kern0pt}

\begin{document}
\asteriskfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know how to repeat a pattern until the bottom limit of the page is reached.

## The question

How to repeat the exact same TikZ pattern to use the entire available space in the page without exceeding page limits?

I thought that a possible way to tackle this problem would be to define a pattern using `\newsavebox` and somehow define a macro that repeats the same box horizontally and vertically until the page limits are reached.

Comment: Is the pattern size know? Then it is just a matter of dividing the page width(and height) by that size and round down to an integer to know the loop iterations.

Comment: @rdrg109 maybe using [\resizebox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409575) you can keep the pattern consistent but scale it as needed.

Comment: @hpekristiansen In the 3 Inkscape images shown above (i.e. when drawing circles, rectangles and sine waves), the pattern size can be inferred from the layout of the graphic. For example, the pattern size of a group of circles is twice the ratio of the biggest circle. I guess, inferring the pattern size gets more difficult as the graphic becomes more complex. For my use case, it would be convenient if I could define a pattern in a `\newsavebox` and find a way to repeat that pattern horizontally and vertically as much as possible. This way, I don't need to infer the pattern size.

Comment: @rdrg109  Please see the code I posted as comments under the accepted answer, to avoid any calculations. Just use vertical and horizontal leaders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\myboxwidth}
\newlength{\myboxheight}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fillPageWithContent}{m}{%
  \newpage
  \sbox\mybox{#1}%
  \setlength{\myboxwidth}{\wd\mybox}%
  \setlength{\myboxheight}{\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox}%
  \noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\myboxwidth, y=\myboxheight]
    % "parse=true" \pgfmathparse's the upper bound in the loop
    \foreach[parse=true] \row in {1, ..., \textwidth/\myboxwidth} {%
      \foreach[parse=true] \column in {1, ..., \textheight/\myboxheight} {%
        \node at (\row, \column) {\usebox\mybox};
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}
\fillPageWithContent{%
  \tikz{%
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.2)
          (0,0) circle (0.4)
          (0,0) circle (0.6)
          (0,0) circle (0.8)
          (0,0) circle (1);
    % enlarge bounding box to make some separation
    \path (-1.05, -1.05) (1.05, 1.05);
  }%
}

\fillPageWithContent{%
  \tikz{
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2,3)
          (.2, .3) rectangle (1.8, 2.7)
          (.4, .6) rectangle (1.6, 2.4)
          (.6, .8) rectangle (1.4, 2.1);
    \path (-.1, -.1) (2.1, 3.1);
  }%
}

\fillPageWithContent{%
  \tikz{
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[rotate=30] (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[rotate=60] (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[rotate=90] (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[rotate=120] (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);    
  }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make the pattern centered within text area, both horizontally and vertically, I

- add `inner sep=0pt` to `tikzpicture` in `\fillPageWithContent` and
- use `\path <coordinate>;` to enlarge the `tikzpicture` from north and west, by the needed amount of shifting.
  This is tricker than classic `\centering` and `\vfill` way, but it works for any size of target rectangle to fill.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\myboxwidth}
\newlength{\myboxheight}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fillPageWithContent}{m}{%
  \newpage
  \sbox\mybox{#1}%
  \setlength{\myboxwidth}{\wd\mybox}%
  \setlength{\myboxheight}{\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox}%
  \noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\myboxwidth, y=\myboxheight, inner sep=0pt]
    % "parse=true" \pgfmathparse's the upper bound in the loop
    \foreach[parse=true] \row in {1, ..., \textwidth/\myboxwidth} {%
      \foreach[parse=true] \column in {1, ..., \textheight/\myboxheight} {%
        \node at (\row, \column) {\usebox\mybox};
      }
    }
    \path
      let \n{xshift} = {\textwidth-\myboxwidth*int(\textwidth/\myboxwidth)},
          \n{yshift} = {\textheight-\myboxheight*int(\textheight/\myboxheight))}
          % Only north and west sides of current bounding box are enlarged,
          % since if all four sides are enlarged, the resulting tikzpicture
          % might be slightly larger than the target rectangle due to rounding
          % errors. May fail in RTL scripts.
          % Also the "pt" following ".5" is important: it makes the x- and
          % y-coordinate with units, so the unit-vectors (which we altered with
          % "x=\myboxwidth, y=\myboxheight") won't be applied.
      in  ([shift={(-.5pt*\n{xshift}, .5pt*\n{yshift})}]
           current bounding box.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}
\fillPageWithContent{%
  \tikz{%
    \draw (0,0) circle (0.2)
          (0,0) circle (0.4)
          (0,0) circle (0.6)
          (0,0) circle (0.8)
          (0,0) circle (1);
    % enlarge bounding box to make some separation
    \path (-1.05, -1.05) (1.05, 1.05);
  }%
}

\fillPageWithContent{%
  \tikz{
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2,3)
          (.2, .3) rectangle (1.8, 2.7)
          (.4, .6) rectangle (1.6, 2.4)
          (.6, .8) rectangle (1.4, 2.1);
    \path (-.1, -.1) (2.1, 3.1);
  }%
}

\fillPageWithContent{%
  \tikz{
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[rotate=30] (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[rotate=60] (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[rotate=90] (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[rotate=120] (0, 0) rectangle (1,1);
  }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you with this method draw the exact same thing, but centered on the page or within textarea - I do not like it when there is just not enough room for one extra like in the middle picture? (I am not the one that needs it, but I am struggling  to center everything with an other method)

Comment: Now looking at your code, I see that you would have the same problem as me. `tikzpagenodes` does not help much as the the picture is not symmetric around `(0,0)`. -I guess it could be made so, but I do not see the "smart" way of doing it - assuming it exist.

Comment: @hpekristiansen See update.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ  Knuth had exactly the same problem. Assume each image was the letter "A". You just loop x-times and TeX will build it for you as a paragraph!

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\mybox
\setbox\mybox\vbox to \textheight{%
\null
\xleaders\hbox{A}
\vfill
}
\usebox\mybox
\null\xleaders\hbox{\usebox\mybox}\hfill\null
\end{document}`

Comment: See the code above, only using leaders. No calculations. Just replace the 'A' with the tikz code:)  It will be nice if you can edit your post and add it as an alternative solution. By the way your tikz skills are impressive.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Knuth designed TeX, perfectly for this. You can avoid all calculations by using both horizontal and vertical leaders.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setmainfont{symbola}
\def\phone{☏}
\def\bullseye{\tikz\draw (0,0) circle (0.2)
          (0,0) circle (0.4)
          (0,0) circle (0.6)
          (0,0) circle (0.8)
          (0,0) circle (1);}

\begin{document}
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox\vbox to .3\textheight{%
\null
\xleaders\hbox{\strut\Huge\kern.2em\bullseye\kern.2em}
\vfill
}
\usebox\mybox
\null\xleaders\hbox{\usebox\mybox}\hfill\null
\end{document}
```

As you can see from the code, by replacing the \bullseye with the \phone, it will also react to sizing commands such as `\Huge` or `\large`. I would recommend to change all coordinates to relative units. Adding also an `\fbox` to the leader, you get the image I have shown.

```
\def\bullseye{\tikz\draw (0,0) circle (0.2)
          (0,0) circle (0.4em)
          (0,0) circle (0.6em)
          (0,0) circle (0.8em)
          (0,0) circle (1em);}
```

Comment: Seems horizontal centering alignment (which @hpekristiansen raised in comments to question and my answer) is still a problem. Maybe that's because I'm not fluent with leader primitives.

Comment: Btw, is the `symbola` font used in your example the one provided in https://github.com/zhm/symbola?

Comment: The symbola font was from Douros  https://localfonts.eu/freefonts/greek-free-fonts/unicode-fonts-for-ancient-scripts/symbola/  It might have been copied by zhm not too sure. I had it for a very long time. Is a nice font.  A perfectly filled  line when centered will still be 1 line long if centered!

Comment: Ah I saw the culprit: I reindented `\bullseye` by adding a newline right after `;` in `\def\bullseye{\tikz \draw ...;}`, which introduced a stray space. Thank you for this `\xleaders` answer.